# Are my soaked capacitors still okay?

Tags: capacitor, water

When the delivery man dropped my capacitors off earlier yesterday he did not ring the doorbell and I had no idea they had arrived on my front step. Then an intense rainstorm showed up and soaked the whole lot of my eight 1500uF, 450V caps. They have a tight plastic coating, and did not seem to consume hardly any water as they dried quick.

Are they okay to use?? How would you recommend to safely test one at a time to see how well they're working?

Maybe it would be best to do a typical charge-up with a rectified variac power source, voltmeter, and discharge into a bleed resistor and ground. I really don't need any extra possible dangers with the high current power supply I'm building, and want to be careful.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would ask the manufacturer: http://www.cde.com/product-support

Comment: Wait, the delivery person left your package on your doorstep unattended? That sounds like it should be worth at least a complaint to the delivery company...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Electrolytic Capacitors are sealed to keep the (liquid) electrolyte in, which inherently makes them sealed to keep liquids *out*. They are also designed to  withstand cleaning with water or other solvents (think domestic dishwasher conditions).

However there is a concern with the shrink-wrapped insulation trapping water and your parts have a rather high voltage rating so you want to make sure the surface of the rubber insulator is dry. Here (from CDE's [application guide](http://www.cde.com/resources/catalogs/AEappGUIDE.pdf)) is the recommended procedure following aqueous cleaning if you want to be 105% safe:

> Aqueous Cleaning
>   Water with a mild detergent may be used to clean aluminum
>   electrolytic capacitors. However, immediately dry the capacitors
>   in hot air at about 85 ºC for 5 or more minutes but not hotter
>   than the capacitors’ maximum storage temperature. Water
>   can become trapped beneath the sleeve which may not be
>   dispelled by evaporation at room temperature. Water can be
>   trapped under the sleeve and cause hydration and discoloration
>   of the aluminum cases; although this does not affect capacitor
>   operation.

Comment: Yep, baking them is definitely the way to go.